# Placing Bibliography String after field value when adapting biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I am adapting `biblatex` to Basque. In this language, some elements need their identification string after the value of the field. For example

```
Ed. by Big Publisher Company
```

should read

```
Big Publisher Company-(a)k argit.
```

I found the way to translate `Ed. by` (I am creating a `basque.ldx` to be shared at some point), but I haven't figured out how to "reverse" the ordering of field values and strings. (Not all fields and orderings should be changed.)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of streamlining some of your posting. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Currently that is really hard. The `.lbx` and all other code (`.bbx`, `.cbx`) is set up in a way that assumes that the bibstring comes before the editor name. It would probably have been better to create the bibstrings in such a way that 'variables' (such as names) can be placed freely within them, but it seems much too late for that now, a major overhaul of all the code would be needed to get that now. So the 'best' way is to change all the relevant macros. That will involve quite bit of code and not a lot of fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at how `byeditor` is used. In `biblatex.def` we have

```
\newbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}
```

So `\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}` is called right before the actual editor name is printed with `\printnames[byeditor]{editor}`.

`bytypestring` is defined as

```
\newbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}
    {\bibstring{by#2}}
    {\ifbibxstring{by\thefield{#1type}}
       {\bibstring{by\thefield{#1type}}}
       {\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}}}
```

so it just gets us the right `byeditor(s)` strings here (if `editorytpe` doesn't ask for anything else).

Since things are set up in exactly this way for all other names as well that means that with standard `biblatex` the by-string will always appear before the name. There is no way for the `.lbx` to change that with `.lbx`-specific methods. And all `.lbx` files are set up in a way that assumes that the `by...` strings always come directly before the name. See also [BibLaTeX customisation: Pages prefix to suffix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135003/35864)

You would have to redefine all these `by...` macros to move `\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{editor}{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}
```

In principle, this can be done from within a `.lbx` file, but it takes many lines of code to redefine all macros involved.

In an ideal world, bibstrings would probably contain 'dummy' variables that can be placed freely within the string so as to allow any order of name and additional text. Unfortunately, the strings are not set up this way at the moment, and switching to that model would require a new implementation of bibstrings, a major overhaul of all `.lbx` files and all style files (standard as well as custom styles). This would probably break backwards compatibility in all ways possible.

Comment: I changed all the macros with "editor" word, until changing `byeditor+others` worked!