# Fix display of page range in bibliography using a babel language

Tags: biblatex, babel

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\addbibresource{testbibfont.bib}
\begin{document}
See \cite{article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The contents of `testbibfont.bib` are:

```
@Article{article,
  author =       "Authors",
  title =        "{Discovery}",
  journal =      "Phys. Journal",
  volume =       "B750",
  year =         2015,
  pages =        "475-493"
}
```

The bibliography is rendered as:

[image]

However, the grammar of the Latvian language stipulates that the range of pages should be given as

> "475.-493. lpp."

instead of

> lpp. 475-493.

The dash there should be en dash.

How to fix?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135003/35864 help?

Comment: If "lpp. 475-493." is incorrect, please open an issue at the `biblatex` bugtracker to get this fixed: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues

Comment: @moewe, is there any hope of adding a dot after the first page number, e.g. replacing `--` with `.--`?

Comment: The linked answer links to a bit in the Hungarian localisation file that should do this https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/magyar.lbx#L106-L137

Comment: @moewe, applying that example I was successful at moving "lpp." to end but how to add the dot?

Comment: As I said https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/magyar.lbx#L106-L137 should also let you get dots, the relevant bit is the `\lbx@hu@mkdottednormrange`. I don't have time tonight to look at this, but if you can't get it to work I might be able to have a look tomorrow. But please let me repeat **if the current behaviour of the Latvian localisation module is incorrect according to Latvian grammar/orthography, please open an issue at** https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues

Comment: @moewe I raised the issue. I don't know how to fiddle with the `\lbx@hu@mkdottednormrange` bit

Comment: Tracked at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/882

Comment: I commented in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/882 with the output of a suggested fix for the language module (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/883). It would be appreciated if you could have a look at the output posted there and say if it looks alright. If you feel adventurous you could also test the pull request branch at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/882, but you will need Biber 2.13 dev for that (https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/binaries/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following discussions in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/882 `latvian.lbx` was changed for `biblatex` 3.13 to produce the expected order of page number and page suffix.

```
\documentclass[latvian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite[380-381]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1, 380.—381. lpp.]//Emma Sigfridsson un Ulf Ryde. ”Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), 377.—395. lpp. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

The "p."/"pp." strings were moved from prefix into suffix position by redefining the internal macro `\blx@mkpageprefix` in the `.lbx` file only for Latvian. Two additional helper macros for the `<postpro>` arguments of `\mknormrange` and `\mkpageprefix` were necessary to get the ordinal ranges right.